# Doing an operation before SUMIF or MATCH-ing multiple values to multiply before summing

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel document with multiple small tables in it. Here, each table describes a single project, and at the end of the worksheet, I want to create a summary that doesn't have "hardcoded" locations so that that when the amount of projects (tables) is adjusted, it doesn't break all the formulas. Basically, it looks like this:

```
    A                           B
1   Project 1
2      Units                    200
3      Price / Unit             10
4      Material / Unit          5
5      Handling / Unit          1
6      Total cost               6
7      Profit Margin / Unit     4
8
9  Project 2
10     Units                    100
11     Price / Unit             5
12     Material / Unit          1
13     Handling / Unit          1
14     Total cost               2
15     Profit Margin / Unit     3
16 
...

19 Summary
20     Units                    =SUMIF( A$1:A19 ; A20 ; B$1:B19 )
21     Material costs           ???
22     Handling costs           ???
23     Total Profit             ???
```

Here, there may be an arbitrary amount of projects and I'm unsure how to create a formula that directly calculates the total material costs (and by the same pattern, Handling and Total Profit). For the total units, I can simply use a `=SUMIF( A$1:A19 ; A20 ; B$1:B19 )` instead of `=B2 + B2` by having the function search col A for the keyword "Units" but in order to do this for the total material costs, I need to multiply first. Eg, it would be `=B2*B4 + B10*B12`.

My first idea was to use an INDEX MATCH approach to extract a subarray from each table and then sum it all up using SUMPRODUCT however the MATCH function unfortunately only returns the first result and I can't get it to output an array of results (I think this is just a limitation with the function?).

I guess it would also be possible to simply add extra lines to each table to pre-calculate these products, but I don't like that solution as it would give the tables a lot of unnecessary extra bloat and I'd really like to solve this in one formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a dirty solution, using [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) formula that works if your using Office 365 :

example calculating total handling cost:

`=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(B:B,A:A="Units"),FILTER(B:B,A:A="Handling / Unit"))`

- `FILTER(B:B,A:A="Units")`, returns an array of values on the right of cells containing "Unit"
- `FILTER(B:B,A:A="Handling / Unit")`, returns an array of values on the right of cells containing  "Handling / Unit"

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick! What makes this solution "dirty" to you?

Comment: It used to be dirtier, now its quite good. But to sum up the formula doesn't differentiate if whether "Units" is located underneath a "Project". For example : `FILTER(B:B,A:A="Unit")` will return an array of 3 because it retrieves 200 from project 1, 100 from project 2 and 300 from summary.